# Make the text cursor disappear - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, input, cursor

I am making an app that should be projected on a wall and I need to put in a very small input box, so the audience won't be able to see it.
I made the font and the box itself very small but the only problem is that the text cursor ( this thing -> | ) keeps blinking and being noticeable.
How can I get rid of it?
Thanks!

Comment: WPF? Use a textblock or label

Comment: That thing is called "Caret".

Comment: Did you try to Google for it? I've found a few answers already here in SO, depending on which framework you probably have an answer already.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I had no idea what it's called, so I couldn't find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make the textbox readonly in that case:

```
yourTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: He is saying cursor, but he really means the caret. Your code would hide the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. The css allows you to hide the blinking cursor in textarea.

In you case just replace the input with `textarea`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title >Text Area with no Carat</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .textarea-wrapper {
                position:relative;
            }
            .textarea-wrapper textarea {
                background-color:white;
            }
            .textarea-wrapper, .textarea-wrapper textarea {
                width:100px;
                height:20px;
            }
            .textarea-wrapper textarea.hidden {
                color:white;
                opacity:0.00;
                filter:alpha(opacity=00);
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $("textarea").addClass("-real-textarea");
                    $(".textarea-wrapper").append("<textarea class=\"hidden\"></textarea>");
                    $(".textarea-wrapper textarea.hidden").keyup(
                        function() {
                            $(".textarea-wrapper textarea.-real-textarea").val($(this).val());
                        }
                    );
                    $(".textarea-wrapper textarea.-real-textarea").focus(
                        function() {
                            $(this).parent().find("textarea.hidden").focus();
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="textarea-wrapper">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm talking about C#.
But thanks, maybe I'll use it in one of my web projects!

Comment: So this is an application?

Comment: Yes. I mentioned it in the post.